# Computer Property not updating on hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a pretty simple model:

```
//models/build
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    shipments: DS.hasMany('shipment')
});
```

I need to update a computer property whenever a new shipment is added or removed, so I'm using my controller, like this:

```
//controllers/build
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        this.get('allShips');
        this.get('ships');
    },
    allShips: Ember.computed.alias('model.shipments'),
    ships: function() {
        console.log('updating ships');
    }.property('model.@each.shipments')
});
```

I'm not consuming the computer properties in my template anywhere, I just need to keep them updated to do some computational work so I'm just getting them in the init function. I'm getting "updating ships" in the console when I'm entering the build route correctly, but after that it won't update no matter how many shipments I add or remove.

I've tried many different properties, `model.ships.@each`, `allShips`, `@each.allShips`, `allShips.@each`, and dozens of all combinations, but all were in vain. I've never had this kind of trouble with computer properties so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of `@each` is incorrect - it should be after `model.shipments`.

As one of the comments state - if you're not accessing properties (e.g. `model.shipments.@each.id` then you should observe `models.shipments.[]`.

For some reason the computed property only updates for me when returning an array - not returning a value or returning any type of value other than an array fails.

Model

```
//models/build
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    shipments: DS.hasMany('shipment')
});
```

Controller

```
//controllers/build
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        this.get('allShips');
        this.get('ships');
    },
    allShips: Ember.computed.alias('model.shipments'),
    ships: function() {
        var ships = this.get('model.shipments');
        console.log('updating ships');
        return [];
    }.property('model.shipments.@each')
});
```

It's probably best to observe `model.shipments.[]` if you're not returning a value:

```
//controllers/build
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    doShipsWork: function() {
        console.log('updating ships');
    }.observes('model.shipments.[]')
});
```

Comment: You probably want `.observes('model.shipments.[]')` -- `@each` is meant for observing properties on individual items of the array, e.g. `ships.@each.location`. And if you're not consuming the property you should use `observes` (this will eliminate the need for the getter in `init` since observing is eager)

Comment: That was actually my mistake. I copied the source wrong. I've tried `model.shipments.@each` and it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you adding shipment objects to a build object?

Comment: `this.get('controllers.build.model.shipments').addObject(shipment);`